# Conditional dataframe calculations based on a columns suffix

Tags: python, pandas

How do I average columns in a dataframe based on the last 3 letters of the column name.  I'm trying to create a new column that will give me the average of all 'bids' in my dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    JPM_bid,   JPM_ask,   Socgen_bid,   Socgen_ask,   UBS_bid,   UBS_ask  ....so forth
0   1.01556    1.01557    1.01552       1.01559       1.01555    1.01558
```

Right now I'm doing calculations like this:

```
df['JPM_spread'] =      df['JPM_ask'].astype(float) - df['JPM_ask'].astype(float)
df['JPM_midpoint'] =    (df['JPM_ask'].astype(float) + df['JPM_ask'].astype(float))/2
df['AVG_bid'] = ""
df['AVG_ask'] = ""
df['JPM_bid_depth'] = ""
...so forth
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you're after: `bid_cols = df.columns.str.contains('bid') for col in bid_cols: df['ave_' + col] = #some calc`?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to perform calculations on either all the bids or all the asks.  I would like to have `df['AVG_bid'] = #avg of all the bids in that row- ignore the ask columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to subset your dataframe with columns which contain `bid` in the column names and calculate the mean. You could subset your columns with `str.contain`, find values for that columns with `loc` and get `mean` for row axis:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('bid')].mean(axis=1)
```

With your part of the dataframe:

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
   JPM_bid,  JPM_ask,  Socgen_bid,  Socgen_ask,  UBS_bid,  UBS_ask
0   1.01556   1.01557      1.01552      1.01559   1.01555  1.01558

In [58]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('bid')].mean(axis=1)
Out[58]:
0    1.015543
dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**

To exclude `0` you could compare your `df` with 0 for subsetted dataframe and then use `mean`. It'll be better if you attach code or example for such dataframe but without data following should work:

```
df_subset = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('bid')]
df_subset[df_subset != 0].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: That works great and it's only one line! Question, is there a way to add something that will skip columns with "0".  I originally had this in my script  `df = df.replace(np.nan, "", regex=True)`, but I had to change it to 0, because i was getting this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: @Tom would you like to skip columns with `bid` but without `0`? Or you're talking about `0` in the cell? If you need to convert value to numeric and make `NaN` for non-numeric you could do `df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x), errors='coerce')` and then you could use `fillna(0)` to fill you `NaN` with 0..

Comment: I would like to average all the columns with bid- however, there are a total of 22 columns with bid in it and some of them have 0 in them.  So when I run the function you gave me, the average is to big because it included the 0s

Comment: @Tom try edited version and consider to attach your dataframe with that parameters.

Answer (score 1):

First get all column names with 'bid' in name.

```
columns_with_bid = [column for column in df.columns if '_bid' in column]
```

Than filter data frame and iterate over rows.

```
df['bid_mean'] = list(row[1].mean() for row in df.filter(columns_with_bid).iterrows())
```

Edit: firstly misinterpreted question to calculate mean for all bid values and not only for rows.